# SAXParseExceptions: catalog of cvc-errors

Tags: java, xml, xsd, sax

Where are the possible XSD-schema validation errors defined?

I am writing a SAX-ErrorHandler and want to deal with them systematically: e.g.

```
public void error(SAXParseException e) throws SAXException {
    if (e.getMessage().startsWith("cvc-pattern-valid:")) {
      .. custom handling, perhaps ignoring ..
    } else if (e.getMessage().startsWith("cvc-type.3.1.3:")) {
      .. custom handling, perhaps ignoring ..
    } else {
        throw (e);
    }
}
```

Any better way to deal with the real error is appreciated too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please take a look [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#validation_failures); it also explains how the numbers come about, etc.

Comment: Great, I was browsing the document, but did not find it!